# Is there anything like service account for Microsoft's OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, service-accounts

I've already used Google Drive with service account (an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user). Do you know whether there is such a thing in OneDrive? I would like to authorize from a script without using web interface. Thank you in advance !